# Databricks Error: AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected. with Delta

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to write to my data lake with Delta on Databricks

```
fulldf = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).option("inferSchema",True).load("/databricks-datasets/flights/")

fulldf.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save('/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Full/')
```

The above produces the following error:

```
AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected.

You are trying to write to `/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Full/` using Databricks Delta, but there is no
transaction log present. Check the upstream job to make sure that it is writing
using format("delta") and that you are trying to write to the table base path.

To disable this check, SET spark.databricks.delta.formatCheck.enabled=false
To learn more about Delta, see https://docs.databricks.com/delta/index.html
```

Any reason for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in my similar situation:

```
%sql CONVERT TO DELTA parquet.`/mnt/lake/BASE/flights/Full/`
```

Answer (score 2):

Such error usually occurs when you have data in another format inside the folder. For example, if you wrote Parquet or CSV files into it before. Remove the folder completely and try again

Comment: I did this using `dbutils.fs.rm`, and found I also had to clean up the metastore with `%sql` `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name` to clear the error, as I'd gone on to add the table previously.