# spark Incompatible format detected - when exporting SQL table to csv file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-database

Using `Apache Spark`, we are trying to export a `Azure SQL` table to a `csv` file in an `Azure Blob Storage`. But we get the following error. Code works only with default format (that seems to be parquet).

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error, and how can it be fixed?

**Error**:

> AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected.

**Code**

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", "MyTable") \
        .option("user", myusername) \
        .option("password", mypassword).load()

jdbcDF.write.csv("abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest")
```

**Remarks**: If we change the last line of the code to the following, it works fine but the exported data file is of the parquet format.
`jdbcDF.write.save("abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest")`

Except for parquet, the error occurs on all other formats (`text`, `json`, etc.), as well. Error occurs on last line of the code. We've verified (by using jdbcDF.Show()) that jdbcDF correctly displays the data

**UPDATE**

1. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274946/1232087) suggestion by creating a new folder but still did not work
2. When I use `jdbcDF.write.format('csv').save("abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest")`, I get the error: `AnalysisException: path abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest already exists.`

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272479/databricks-error-analysisexception-incompatible-format-detected-with-delta), if you already have data in that folder, you may see an error like this.

Comment: @ogdenkev I had red that post (and anther similar post). As per suggestion of those two posts, I created a new folder, but still exact same error.

Comment: got it. What if you set some of the CSV options? Or try `jdbcDF.write.format('csv').save()`?

Comment: @ogdenkev I tried suggestion and just added an **UPDATE** section to my post.

Comment: have you tried using `option('mode', 'overwrite')`?

Answer (score 0):

> AnalysisException: path
> abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest already
> exists.

You are getting above error since there must be already a file exist with the same name.

Use different file name or use `SaveMode` as `Override` and it should work fine.

Try this:

```
df.write.csv("abfss://myFolder@MyADLSGen2Account.dfs.core.windows.net/MyTest",mode="overwrite")
```

Refer [PySpark: DataFrame Write Modes](https://dbmstutorials.com/pyspark/spark-dataframe-write-modes.html) to know more about writing to a file.